# Why is the result of chr(0x24) + chr(0x84) different in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was using python to solve the protostar challenges from [exploit-exercises](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack3/). And I was surprised by the different output for this code with python 3.

```
payload = chr(0x24) + chr(0x84)
print (payload)
```

In terminal:

```
$ python exploit-stack3.py | xxd
00000000: 2484 0a                                  $..
$ python3 exploit-stack3.py | xxd
00000000: 24c2 840a                                $...
```

Could someone please explain where the c2 is comming from ?

Comment: The second one is in UTF8

Comment: Python 3 `str` type corresponds to Python 2 `unicode` type. Python 2 `str` type is `bytes` type in Python 3.

Comment: I guess that it has to do with utf-8. But a litte more details would be welcome. I don't really understand what char had the c2 added.
>>> chr(0xc284)
'슄'
>>> chr(0x24)
'$'
>>> chr(0x24c2)
'Ⓜ'

Comment: See Ignacio's answer, `chr(0x84).encode() == b'\xc2\x84'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's coming from [encoding the character as UTF-8](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

```
>>> '\x84'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x84'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, printable characters in ASCII end on 0x7E (tilda: `~`). Python 2 uses ASCII encoding, Python3 uses unicode. 0x84 exceeds ASCII charset that's why output will be different.